# Value of type x.y cannot be converted to type x.y when returning object from function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp.net website which has an added webservice reference. Everything worked until recently when I started migrating some of the functions into their own classes. Everything works if I keep all the code inside the page.

When I make a Public Function X inside my functions class which returns a response object type of the webservice I get an error in the page calling this function:

Value of type 'wsRef.ResponseObject' cannot be converted to 'wsRef.ResponseObject'

Webservice:
Referenced as **wsRef**

Page:

```
Dim myFunctionsClass As new csFunctions
Dim resObj As New wsRef.ResponseObject
resObj = myFunctionsClass.callWS("ABC1234")
```

Class csFunctions:

```
Public Function callWS(ByVal param As String) As wsRef.ResponseObject
  '/ call ws etc, get result back and return it
  Return wsResObject
End Function
```

I don't understand why this exception, objects are clearly of the same type, they are both specified from the same namespace (wsRef).

Comment: If you open Object Browser, do you find that you've actually got two copies of (one or more) assemblies?

Comment: If you mean the webservice reference then no, I can only see one wsRef object in Object Browser.

Comment: No, I meant assemblies. I.e. if your project is called `ABC.DEF`, do you actually see two `ABC.DEF` assemblies in the object browser (or any other assemblies)

Comment: There are no multiple assemblies. I just tried this in another website and am getting the same error, I'm guessing I missed something with namespaces and using objects from different namespaces in my code.